# Why JDK location can't change on Android Studio 3?

Tags: java, android-studio

I was working on android studio. In this time I open another java software. After this my studio show below error.

[image: image1]

If I open JDK setting and change the jdk location, it change but not save. If I restart studio the default location come again and show the error.

[image: image2]

I don't find any help on google and youtube. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you unceck the box "Use embedded JDK (recommended)" it should allow you to set a path to JDK manually. Please post back if there are any other issues.

However, I'd recommend you let Android Studio install its own JDK where it wants it, and then you install a separate one (or even better, make the other programs go look for JRE under the android studio path)...

Comment: Thank you. I uninstall studio and install again. The problem solve! I don't know why!

Comment: Welcome, no worries!